# How to prevent style propagation to the next LI element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `article` with a list (`ol`) of sentences, one per line. A user can hit Enter to create another sentence on a new line, which appends a new `li`. A user can also emphasize some text in a sentence (using a button, but it's irrelevant for the sake of the question). The problem is that when hitting Enter after an emphasized text, the next `li` also "inherits" the emphasis. How can I make the new `li`s vanilla?

HTML

```
<article id="xml" contenteditable="true">
  <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li><em>world</em></li>
  </ol>
</article>
```

CSS

```
body {
  counter-reset: item !important;
}

article#xml ol {
  list-style: none;
}

article#xml ol li {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 14px;
  counter-increment: item;
}

#xml ol li:before {
  content: counter(item);
  color: #888;
  border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  margin-right: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

E.g. adding an item after 'hello' creates a vanilla `li`, while doing so after 'world' creates an emphasized one.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/dimidd1/pen/ZyYBNZ)

Comment: I think the code for the emphasizing button is the key here. Most likely it fails to add a closing `em` tag ..?

Comment: It's added correctly, e.g. `<em>world</em>`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it by disabling the default browser callback, and implementing everything manually. This also solved another bug I had (hitting Enter twice in a row would remove an `li`, instead of creating a new one).

```
$('#xml').on('keydown', function(e) {
  // 13 is Enter
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // traverse ancestors till the LI
    let oldLi = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
    while (oldLi.nodeName != 'LI') {
      oldLi = oldLi.parentNode;
    }
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');
    $(oldLi).after(newLi);

    // set cursor to the beginning of the new LI
    const range = document.createRange();
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const newText = document.createTextNode('');
    newLi.appendChild(newText);
    range.setStart(newText, 0);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

The only downside is that the cursor is first shifted before the number, and returns to its correct position after the first char entered.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/dimidd1/pen/gRbmmN)

Answer (score 0):

you want one of these i think.

only style the first one.

CSS

```
ol li:first {
....
}
```

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li></li> /*styling from the above*/
    <li></li> /* NO styling from the above rule */
</ol>
```

prevent style propagation to the next LI element

CSS

```
ol > li {
....
}
```

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li> /*styling from the above*/
        <li></li> /* NO styling from the above rule*/
    </li>
</ol>
```

know that you can combined them, i was just showing for ease of illustration.
so this is also valid.

```
ol > li: first {
....
}
```

try apply as you need:

```
ol li:before {
   //only rules for before
}
ol li:first {
   //only rules for before
}
ol li {
   //rules for all li within ol
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the `before` pseudo-selector for numbering.

Comment: @dimid then you probably need another class on the element

Comment: Also my `li`s need to be siblings rather than nested.

Comment: How can I add a class to `li`s? They're added by the browser after the user hits Enter, not by my code.

Comment: @dimid can you have two rules... before and first?

Comment: Right, but I need it to apply to children `li`s, not just the first one.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your solution, could you fork my codepen (or a js fiddle) and add your changes?

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. Perhaps I'm missing something, could you specify the rules in each selector?

Comment: @DanielBeck please share your thoughts PS noting i have stated is incorrect.... i was simply showing options as i'm not sure how dumid is unable to archive what he wants... if you know then please by all means  post your answer and i will remove mine. Stating its simple irrelevant is so far from the truth... care to expand? honestly I'm not sure you read anything correctly. depending how how he did his emphasized text the above could radically simply his coding but only adding styles and using "no style propagation" which basically does what he wanted.

Comment: You read the wording of the question, but apparently didn't look at the code -- contenteditable copies the styling tags (such as `<em>` into the next `<li>`) when creating a new one; css rules aren't in play here at all.

Comment: The incorrect information is the invalid `<li><li></li></li>` structure, and whatever it is you're trying to do with `:before`.

Comment: @DanielBeck there was no code at the time!!!! please look at time stamps

Comment: That, too, is incorrect. There's no edit history for the question, it is now as it was originally written.

Comment: Basically you saw the words "style propagation" in the title and jumped to the conclusion that it was a CSS question -- without looking at the HTML in the question which shows that the styling is coming from an `<em>` tag, not a CSS rule.

Comment: (Apologies for accidentally deleting my initial comment, which makes this conversation look a bit unprompted now)